# Getting error - Exception calling "Rename" with "1" argument(s): "Could not rename this site collection. The URL specified is already in use."

Tags: powershell, error, spsite

I'm trying to rename an SPSite to a URL that had been previously deleted.

So I go like this  (note - urls redacted)

```
$site = get-spsite <mysecondurl>
$site.rename('myfirsturl')
```

However, when I run this, I'm getting this error.

> Exception calling "Rename" with "1" argument(s): "Could not rename this site collection. The URL specified is already in use."

I've gone to `Get-SPSite`, and the URL I want to rename to is not there.
I've gone to `Get-SPDeletedSite` and it was there so I removed the site using `Get-SPRemovedSite`.

However, I'm still getting the same error.

Where else should I check to ensure this URL is not being used?

Answer (score 0):

[Todd Klindt suggests](http://www.toddklindt.com/blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=573) the following

> ```
> $site = Get-SPSite http://portal.contoso.com/sites/foo
> $uri = New-Object System.Uri("http://foo.contoso.com")
> $site.Rename($uri)
> ```
>
> To get 100% success I have to force the Content Database to refresh
>   its site map with this:
>
> ```
> ((Get-SPSite http://foo.contoso.com).contentdatabase).RefreshSitesInConfigurationDatabase
> ```
>
> and run an `IISReset`. The `IISReset` isn’t always necessary, but it’s
>   good to plan for it.

That would seem to include some relevant steps which weren't part of your approach.

Comment: this didn't work. It was weird, I ended up having to manually delete the URL from the SiteMapURL table. I'm not even sure why it was in there since I had already deleted it