# Could not rename this site collection. The URL specified is already in use

Tags: site-collection, rename, host-header

I am trying to rename a site collection, using scripts something like this:

```
$site = Get-SPSite http://portal.contoso.com/sites/foo
$uri = New-Object System.Uri("https://foo.contoso.com")
$site.Rename($uri)
```

I used stsadm:

`stsadm -o renamesite -oldurl http://test.matt.com -newurl https://test.matt.com`

But does not work and I keep getting this error.

> Exception calling "Rename" with "1" argument(s): "Could not rename this site collection. The URL specified is already in use."

I did a test on another web application using the scripts above, and that worked just fine. Not in this one though.

This one has three zone:

- Default
- Extranet
- Internet

I got the scripts from these urls:

- [change-host-named-site-collection-url](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/svarukala/2014/05/06/change-host-named-site-collection-url/)
- [getting-error-exception-calling-rename-with-1-arguments-could-not-rename](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/218675/getting-error-exception-calling-rename-with-1-arguments-could-not-rena)

What could be the problem?

**Update:**
I am updating a site collection host header to a site collection host header.

**Update 2**
SSL is enabled at Web Application level. There are 500+ site collections

Comment: R u trying to rename path based site collection to host name sitecollection?

Comment: I am trying to rename from `host name site collection` to `host name site collection`.

Comment: Ur code is confusing? Are you trying to change the http to https or something from https://oldurl.com to newurl.com ? Can you run get-spite against new url and see if it returns anything.

Comment: trying to change http to https

Comment: IS SSL configured at Web Application level? how many site collections in the Web Application?

Comment: SSL is enabled at Web Application level. There are 500+ site collections

Comment: You can't use rename url method to change the url rather you have to use the set-spsiteurl  method...you have to make sure that's site does not exist before in that farm....if was there before then make sure it should not anymore

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to do an `backup-spsite` and then remove the site, and finally restore it back.

Use this code. It has worked for me. Modify the url parameters as needed and the path of the file.

```
Backup-SPSite https://currentsite -Path D:\backupsite.bak
Remove-SPSite –Identity https://currentsite –Confirm:$False 
Restore-SPSite https://newsitesiteurl -Path D:\backupsite.bak -HostHeaderWebApplication https://webapphostnameurl.com
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you check whether any site with same name is listed in SPDeletedSite?
Use PowerShell script to see the list of deleted site

```
==>Get-SPDeletedSite
```

If you can see the site with the same name,copy the **identity** of site and remove it using below powershell command

```
Remove-SPDeletedSite –Identity 9d0ed313-0353-4cec-817a-a491a8c5fc26
```

Comment: I have used `Get-SPDeletedSite` and there were no sites with this name