# Restore-SPSite : Invalid object name 'Sites'

Tags: backup, content-database, restore

I tried to rename the site collection host header ([see post here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/232417/could-not-rename-this-site-collection-the-url-specified-is-already-in-use/232418#232418)) and it did not work, so I found this [blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kaevans/2013/09/09/moving-path-based-to-host-named-site-collections/) and thought I could give `Backup-SPSite`, `Remove-SPSite` and `Restore-SPSite` a try. I used this code below, of course changed the values.

```
Backup-SPSite http://server_name/sites/site_name -Path C:\Backup\site_name.bak 
Remove-SPSite –Identity http://server_name/sites/site_name –Confirm:$False 
Restore-SPSite http://www.example.com -Path C:\Backup\site_name.bak -HostHeaderWebApplication http://server_name
```

When I tried to restore it back, it said that it could not open database

> Restore-SPSite : Cannot open database "SP_Content_1" requested by the
>   login. The login failed. Login failed for user 'domain\svc_farm'. At
>   line:1 char:1
>   + Restore-SPSite https://newsite -Path D:\backupsite.bak -HostHeader ...
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (Microsoft.Share...dletRestoreSite:SPCmdletRestoreSite)
>   [Restore-SPSite], SqlException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell.SPCmdletRestoreSite

The database `SP_Content_1` does not exist actually. How is it trying to log in when it does not exist? Therefore, I created a database, gave the user access to the database and tried it again.

```
Restore-SPSite http://www.example.com -Path C:\Backup\site_name.bak -HostHeaderWebApplication http://server_name
```

This time I am getting the following error.

> Restore-SPSite : Invalid object name 'Sites'. At line:1 char:1
>   + Restore-SPSite https://sitename.com -Path D:\backupsite.bak -HostHeader ...
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (Microsoft.Share...dletRestoreSite:SPCmdletRestoreSite)
>   [Restore-SPSite], SqlException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell.SPCmdletRestoreSite

The environment is the same one. I have used the `Get-SPDeletedSite` and there are no deleted sites as I cleared them all.

Any idea how should I proceed from here?

Answer (score 1):

try to use something like this:

```
Restore-SPSite -Identity http://newurl -DatabaseServer "SQLS01\instance" -Path D:\backup.bak -DatabaseName "SP_Content" -HostHeaderWebApplication https://webapphostheaderurl
```

I have included the databaseserver and databasename in the script.
Let us know what you get.

Comment: it worked!! but I am getting this warning:

`WARNING: The port specified for the new host header site does not match any known bindings in the specified Web Application.  The new site will not be acce
ssible if the Web Application is not extended to an IIS Web Site serving this port.`

Comment: Is ur hostname site collection using different port than the web application itself?

Comment: no it is using the same port. 443